# How to assign values to cases by group

Tags: r, group-by, group

This is sample of data I am working with:

[image]

Here is the data splited into different files, one for 2 elements by group and anothe one with 3 elements by group

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13NcZ1eDRz7RfPIV0w-bOsF6kS1ePSQ9j?usp=sharing

In the column inspection I want to assing this codes by group (group variables are Code, Area, Floor and Box).

For each group combination:

- If result=1 in one the cases and the other has result=4, inspection=1 to case with result=4 and inspection=2 to result=1
- If result=1 in one the cases and the other has result=3, inspection=1 to case with result=3 and inspection=2 to result=1
- If result=1 in one the cases and the other has result=1, inspection=1 one of the cases and to the other inspection=2.

How can I make this adjustment to inspection variable by each case groups to get the result in this image?

[image]

Then, I have cases with 3 elements per group:

[image]

For each group combination:

- If result=1 in one the cases and the other two has result=4 and result=4, inspection=1 to first case with result=4, the second case with result=4 asign inspection=0 and inspection=2 to result=1
- If result=1 in one the cases and the other two has result=4 and result=0, inspection=1 to the case with result=4, inspection=0 to case with result=0 and inspection=2 to result=1
- If result=1 in all the cases, inspection=1 in one of the cases and to the other inspection=2, as we can see on the image below

[image]

How can I do that asignation?

Comment: What if a group have 1, 3, and 4? what will be the values for Inspection?

Comment: In that case, it depends on the group. If have a result 1, 3, and 4, I will like to add inspection (2,0,1). How can I do that?

Comment: I think your question is not clear because there are other cases where we don't know the inspection values

Comment: I updated the question with the cases with 3 elements per group

Answer (score 1):

How about just using the order of `Result` to rearrange `c(2,1)`, like this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Code, Area, Floor, Box) %>% 
  mutate(Inspection = c(2,1)[order(Result)])
```

Output:

```
  Code   Area Floor   Box Result Inspection
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
1 10101    11   108     1      4          1
2 10101    11   108     1      1          2
3 10101    11    89     1      1          2
4 10101    11    89     1      1          1
5 10101    11    90     1      1          2
6 10101    11    90     1      3          1
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply it using conditionals? Cause I have group cases of 3 and 4 and I will like to apply similar results?

Comment: you need to specify the full set of rules. My code works on the rules you gave. If you specify the rules for cases 3 and 4 (or above in response to @akrun's question about 2,0,1), then I could revise my answer..

Comment: In cases with three elements, I want to asign inspection 2 to all the cases within the group with result=1. If there is two or more cases with result=3 or result=4, I wanto assign inspection=1 to only othe cases with this result (result=4) and inspection 0 to result=0

Comment: is that the full set of possibilities?  For example, what if you have a two-element case, where you have 3 and 4?. Also, here you say assign inspection 2 to all cases within a group that has result=1, but above, you indicate a 3-element group with all result=1, will have inspection=1 for one of those rows, and inspection =2 for the other rows

Comment: In the two-element case, If there a case with 3 and 4, I will like to assign inspection 0 to both of them

Comment: I'm sorry, too many cases still have not been described.  Also, your data are in images, which makes it difficult to use. Perhaps update your questions with full information, and perhaps I'll try to answer it.

Comment: I uploaded the files with all the cases to update inspection variable based on the cases conditions